# Rails 6 - rendering JS fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a new project on Rails 6. I came across an issue with rendering JS file.

```rb
    def create
      @member = Member.new(member_params)

      if @member.save
        redirect_to members_path
      else
        render js: :new
      end
    end
```

Once save actions fails I wanna reder new.js.erb file but insted get weird error not related with my project files.

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):

body.each do |part|
  parts << part
  (digest ||= Digest::SHA256.new) << part unless part.empty?
end

[digest && digest.hexdigest.byteslice(0, 32), parts]

rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:69:in `<<'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:69:in `block in digest_body'
...
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:682:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Besides, I found it happens every time during using `render js: anyfile`

environment.js

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

Has anyone come across that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not doing it right. Try like below -

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @member.save
    return redirect_to members_path
  else
    format.js { render :new }
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I did it wrong way before. Besides, it's worth to mention `remote: true` is needed in form and then just `render :new` is enough